# Unable to create multiple droppable elements inside a loop using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create many droppable elements inside a loop. Here is the code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for(var j = 0; j < 20; j++){

        $("#main").append( '<a  "href="javascript:void(0);" id="click'+i+'-'+j+'"  onclick="change_to_blocked('+i+','+j+')"><img id="image'+i+'-'+j+'" src="http://localhost/free.png" />');
        $("#main").append('');
        tmp1 = i;
        tmp2 = j;   
        $('#image'+i+'-'+j).droppable({

   drop: function(e,ui) {
        $('#image'+(i)+'-'+(j)).attr('src','/bot.png');
        console.log(i);

           }
  });
}
    $("#main").append('<br>');  }
```

However, it only applies to the last value of the loop.

Comment: The normal way would be to use $(this) instead of $('#image'+(i)+'-'+(j)) inside drop function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a `closure` otherwise at the time the events occur the values of `i` and `j` will be the values of the last iteration of the loop.

One way is to wrap the code within loop in an `IIFE - Immediately Invoked Function Expression`

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < 20; j++) {

        (function (i, j) {
            $("#main").append('<a  "href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="return showIndexes('+i +','+j+')">Item # '+i+'-'+j+'</a><br>');
        })(i, j); //params used in the IIFE

    }
}
```

By passing the values as arguments of the function they are closed in the function and won't be changed by subsequent iterations

Some of the html rendering was left out for clarity

When looping over arrays with jQuery, you can create a closure by using `$.each` which will provide you the index as first argument of the callback

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ygbtky0f/)**</kbd>